# When do we use Retrieve and Retrieve Multiple Messages in Plugin Registration tool?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

In plugin i used services but when should i go for Messages like Retrieve and Retrieve Multiple

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamics CRM 2011 Plugin Retrieve and Retrieve Multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048688/dynamics-crm-2011-plugin-retrieve-and-retrieve-multiple)

Answer (score 0):

When we want to intercept and alter the responses back to the use for a query.

For example you could remove certain fields or make your own "calculated" field in a plugin.

Comment: could you briefly explain i did't get it